# Обработчик событий Onclick

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго времени суток! Есть такая конструкция:

```
<input type="button" class="jqModal" value= "LOGIN" onclick="show()"/>
<div class="jqmWindow" id="dialog"> //это должно появляться при клике             
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="login" />
</div>
```

В head я прописал обработчик:

```
function show() {
    var rd = $(".jqmWindow");
    rd.style.display = 'block';    
}
```

Подскажите, почему не работает? И как сделать, чтобы окно появлялось при клике на текст или картинку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В примере у вас div по умолчанию отображается. Для начала его нужно скрыть :) И если уже использовать JQuery, то пишите так:

html

```
<input type="button" class="jqModal" value= "LOGIN"/>
<div class="jqmWindow" id="dialog" style="display:none;">

</div>
```

javascript

```
$(".jqModal").click (function () {
    $(".jqmWindow").show();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
function show() { 
var rd = $(".jqmWindow").show(1000);
}
```

или

```
function show() { 
var rd = document.getElementById('dialog'); 
rd.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Не?

Comment: Не работает.

Comment: @Александр Габараев, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.